# How to adjust position of parameter description in an equation?

Tags: equations, ieeetran

I'm trying to move the "where" further to the left to make it look nicer. How can I do that?

Please do suggest if you have any idea to make it better. I also want the "where" part always goes with these equation so I embeded inside the equation format.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{booktabs,capt-of}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq: label}
\begin{split}
x_{a,\Phi_1} &=m_k\\
x_{a,\Phi_2} &=n_k\\
x_{ph,k} &= \frac{a_1 Q +  b_1(1-2Q) }{P}x_n\\
\textit{where }P&=(1-2|c_1|)Q+(1-3|c_1|)(1-2Q).
\end{split}  
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply move it to text?

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{equation}
\label{eq: label}
\begin{split}
x_{a,\Phi_1} & = m_k\\
x_{a,\Phi_2} & = n_k\\
x_{ph,k} &= \frac{a_1 Q +  b_1(1-2Q) }{P}x_n   
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $P=(1-2|c_1|)Q+(1-3|c_1|)(1-2Q)$.

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
If you persist that your "description" is par of equation (what I would not do, but this is up to you), you may use this solution:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb} % <---

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{align}
\label{eq: label}
x_{a,\Phi_1} & = m_k        \notag  \\
x_{a,\Phi_2} & = n_k                \\
x_{ph,k}     & = \frac{a_1 Q +  b_1(1-2Q) }{P}x_n
                            \notag  \\[1ex]
\shortintertext{where 
           $P = \mathrlap{(1-2|c_1|)Q+(1-3|c_1|)(1-2Q)}$}
                            \notag 
\end{align}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may reduce vertical space after equation with adding:

```
...
\end{align}

\vspace{-\baselineskip}\noindent
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

In this case result is:

[image]

Comment: but would  doing that way make the description separated from equation in any case?

Comment: Is not separated. It follows  the equation.  That is usual way for writing such equation. However, you can include it in equation as is shown in addendum to answer.

Comment: I wrote it like that at first but then I worried that sometimes equations is in one page and the description is in another page which is probably a bit hard to read. But I think I'll follow your first suggestion.

Comment: @hana, believe me, my first suggestion is way to go. The very same is suggested in other answer too (written by expert for math and (La)TeX, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)

Comment: I see. I'll go with the first suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I'd not look for awkward alignments. The “where” text is not part of the equation and you can safely place it just after the equations. You readers will see the specification and mentally do the substitution.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{equation}
\label{eq: label}
\begin{split}
x_{a,\Phi_1} &=m_k\\
x_{a,\Phi_2} &=n_k\\
x_{ph,k} &= \frac{a_1 Q +  b_1(1-2Q) }{P}x_n
\end{split}  
\end{equation}
where $P=(1-2|c_1|)Q+(1-3|c_1|)(1-2Q)$.

\lipsum[2][1-3]

\end{document}
```

Note that no page/column break is possible between `\end{equation}` and the following text, provided no blank line in the input is used.

Note that I loaded `newtx` so to make math symbols agree with the main Times text font. You don't need `amsfonts`.

[image]

You might also save some space:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{equation}
\label{eq: label}
\begin{gathered}
x_{a,\Phi_1}=m_k\qquad
x_{a,\Phi_2}=n_k \\[0.5ex]
x_{ph,k} = \frac{a_1 Q +  b_1(1-2Q) }{P}x_n
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
where $P=(1-2|c_1|)Q+(1-3|c_1|)(1-2Q)$.

\lipsum[2][1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.